# Character encoding issue when writing a file to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

When I try creating a file on S3 with special characters like `‘’ “” – — é` in them, incorrect data gets written on the files, and weird characters appear in file. I am using the official [`aws-sdk` ruby gem](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby)  provided by Amazon. Below is sample code:

```
@bucket = AppConfig.s3_bucket
@s3 = AWS::S3.new
file = @s3.buckets[@bucket].objects['amit/test']
file.write("‘test1’ “test2” test–test—test3 é-test", :acl => :public_read)
```

I have also tried:

```
file.write("‘test1’ “test2” test–test—test3 é-test", :acl => :public_read, :content_type => 'text/html')
file.write("‘test1’ “test2” test–test—test3 é-test", :acl => :public_read, :content_type => 'text/plain')
file.write("‘test1’ “test2” test–test—test3 é-test", :acl => :public_read, :content_type => 'text/plain', :content_encoding => 'utf-8')
```

The output file looks like this:
`â€˜test1â€™ â€œtest2â€ testâ€“testâ€”test3 Ã©-test`

I have tried with aws-sdk version `1.11.1` and `1.65.0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like you just need to specify the character encoding of the file. The string you are seeing, `â€˜test1â€™ â€œtest2â€ testâ€“testâ€”test3 Ã©-test`, is what your test string looks like if you view it as Windows-1252 encoded rather than UTF-8. If you are looking at in in the browser (which usualy defaults to 1252 if there is no encoding set), try changing the encoding the browser is using to UTF-8 (the menu would be something like `View → Encoding`).

I’m not familiar with the AWS api, but a look at [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#write-instance_method) suggest you can specify the content type with the `:content_type` option to the `write` call. Try:

```
file.write("‘test1’ “test2” test–test—test3 é-test", :acl => :public_read, :content_type => "text/plain; charset=utf-8")
```

(Or you might want `text/html` instead of `text/plain`.)

This should, if I’ve understood the docs, cause AWS to set the content-type header when retrieving the object.

This all depends on whatever you’re using to fetch the object reading the header. If not you might have to configure your client to tell it the data is UTF-8.

Comment: Works! But setting :content_type as `text/html` doesn't work, and neither does setting `:content_encoding => 'utf-8'` parameter, but passing it along with `:content_type` as you suggested works fine! Probably AWS docs are buggy and `:content_encoding` doesn't work as suggested.

Comment: @amit_saxena `content_encoding` is for things like compression (e.g. you might have a header `Content-encoding: gzip`). Another alternative for HTML could be to just set the `content_type` to `text/html` (i.e. no `; charset=UTF-8`) and use a `<meta>` tag in the HTML itself, but usually you’d want to have the encoding in the header if you can.

Answer (score 1):

It’s possible one of your filenames are unicode and you do not have the appropriate locale set to handle it.

Check:

```
$ locale

LANG=
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_ALL=
```

The fix:

```
$ locale -a |grep en_US
en_US.ISO8859-1
en_US.ISO8859-15
en_US.US-ASCII
en_US.UTF-8

$ export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Note: Depending on your shell, you will need to use the appropriate method for setting environment variables, `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` or `setenv LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8` or other.

Stolen from: http://randysofia.com/2014/06/06/aws-cli-and-your-locale/

Comment: We are talking about writing the file to Amazon S3 here and not on local storage.

Comment: Well, @amit_saxena, I'm glad you didn't need to fix what I had a problem with, but I can assure you that my answer was connected with `aws s3 sync` command.